# Duplicate Entry error on field that isn't primary key

Tags: php, mysql

I'm doing an insert MySQL query in PHP with something like this:

```
$inserto= sprintf("INSERT INTO processing (orderid, ordert, usr, status, date, orderType) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)",
    GetSQLValueString($OID,"int"),
    GetSQLValueString($tempbody,"text"),
    GetSQLValueString($_COOKIE[TENNuser],"text"),
    GetSQLValueString("0","int"),
    GetSQLValueString(date("d-m-Y"),"text"),
    GetSQLValueString('1','int'));
```

Sometimes it works fine, other times I get a duplicate entry error. I know why it's happening, it's because some orderid are technically the same sometimes (which is normal). The problem is that orderid isn't the primary key. I have an "id" field that auto increments and THAT is the primary key.

Any idea what could be happening?

Comment: duplicate errors occur anytime you have ANY index that is defined as 'unique' and insert (obviously) a duplicate record. It's not restricted to just primary key field(s).

Comment: Must be a Monday thing, I completely forgot to check the indexes and it's still set to the orderid field. Fixed it. :) Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Didn't check the indexes and there it was, the orderid field was set to UNIQUE.

It's going to be a long day. Thanks Marc B.

Comment: Hint: It is perfectly ok, valid and allowed to accept a self-answer.

Comment: Must have forgot to, I couldn't accept my own answer for 2 days.